# How to use Swift Protocols with Generic methods and Generic Types

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a class `StateMachine<A>`

```
final class StateMachine<A> {

    private var previousState: State? = nil
    private var currentState: State
    private var content: A?
    var delegate: StateMachineDelegate?
    var state: State = .loading {
        didSet {
            previousState = currentState
            currentState = state
        }
    }

    init(currentState: State, delegate: StateMachineDelegate?) {
        self.currentState = currentState
    }
}
```

and a delegate protocol `StateMachineDelegate`

```
protocol StateMachineDelegate {
    func updateWith(content: A)
}
```

I'm trying to express that if the StateMachine is created with type A, the delegate should implement the method `func updateWith(content: A)` which accepts a parameter of the same type A. Is this possible?

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems now: you can't put nested types in generics (`enum State`); you must initialize all non-optional properties in your `init`; you must specify `associatedtype` in your delegate protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd implement what you're asking for by adding another type parameter:

```
final class StateMachine<A, Delegate: StateMachineDelegate> where Delegate.A == A {

    private var previousState: State? = nil
    private var currentState: State
    private var content: A?
    var delegate: Delegate?
    var state: State = .loading {
        didSet {
            previousState = currentState
            currentState = state
            delegate?.updateWith(content: state)
        }
    }

    init(currentState: State, delegate: Delegate?) {
        self.currentState = currentState
    }
}

protocol StateMachineDelegate {
    associatedtype A
    func updateWith(content: A)
}
```

But I wouldn't do it this way. If your delegate really is just an update method, then a closure is a better solution:

```
final class StateMachine<A> {    
    // ...
    private var content: A?
    var notify: (A) -> Void

    var state: State = .loading {
        didSet {
            previousState = currentState
            currentState = state
            notify(state)
        }
    }

    init(currentState: State, notify: @escaping (A) -> Void) {
        self.currentState = currentState
        self.notify = notify
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellant answer! Thank you.